# How to call YAML data in a Gherkin Feature File

Tags: intellij-idea, yaml, gherkin

I want to run a scenario but my feature gherkin file doesn't recognize YAML data and consider it as a comment, I'm talking about the last line

Please can you help me with that?

```
@config-booster-config.yml

Feature: Login
  @login-01
  Scenario Outline: <ID_Iteration> - login scenario
    Given user logged with <email> <password>
    #When user logs out
    #Then user is redirected Login page

    Examples:
  ## ${booster.login}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the application.yml when I change it it works!